# the p5js input + value function

Tags: javascript, function, web, input, p5.js

I found a some code to create an input textbx in p5.js but I do not understand what the last line is doing and was wondering if someone can help

```
 function greet() {  //creates a function called greet
 const name = input.value();  //sets value in the textbox to name
 greeting.style("color", "#8800FF")  //sets the greeting color
 greeting.html('Hello ' + name + '!'); //sets the html  
 input.value('');
 }
```

what is the line input.value(''); doing.  When I comment it out it doesnt seem to do anything.  I am really confused, and I want to make sure I understand what is going on here so I can try and manipulate this and add it to a program I am working on.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the function is called when the user maybe clicks a button?
The value the user inputted, i.e. his name, is saved into the variable called name.
Then the function will show 'Hello name!'.
And then in the last line it just resets the input to an empty string so that the user can enter something else.
That also means that this function is not creating the input itself. It just uses the entered value to do something with it.

Comment: Well that makes so much sense now, I honestly just gave up and handed it in.  Thank you so much!